# Read nfc in app and get value of text

Tags: java, android, webview, sdk, nfc

i have a standard webview app. im trying to impliment NFC reading so when an NFC tag is scanned it opens the app if not already open and goes to a custom web address using the app. i for the life of me cannot work out how to do. the code for the web app is below i am new to this and have no idea how to add nfc to existing app.

Android Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="web.webapp">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" >
    <activity android:name=".WebActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

java

```
    Webactivity.java

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.DownloadListener;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class WebActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private WebView webView;
private boolean backButtonPressed = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_web);

loadWebView();
}

private void loadWebView() {
String URL = getString(R.string.url);
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.clearCache(true);
disableBrowserPopup();
enableDownloadListener();
enableMediaVolume();
enableJavascript();
enableZoom();
webView.loadUrl(URL);
}

private void enableMediaVolume() {
setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
}

private void enableZoom() {
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
}

private void enableJavascript() {
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
}

private void enableDownloadListener() {
webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
long contentLength) {
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(intent);
}
});
}

private void disableBrowserPopup() {
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
view.loadUrl(url);
return true;
}
});
}

private void exitPopup() {
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
.setMessage("Exit " + getString(R.string.app_name) + "?")
.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
WebActivity.super.onBackPressed();
System.exit(0);
}
})
.setNegativeButton("No", null)
.show();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
if (webView.canGoBack()) {
webView.goBack();
return;
}
if (backButtonPressed) {
exitPopup();
return;
}
backButtonPressed = true;
Toast.makeText(this, "Press BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
backButtonPressed = false;
}
}, 2000);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
exitPopup();
return true;
}
return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event);
}

}
```

any help would be fantastic

Answer (score 0):

Everything about using NFC for Android is in the docs [NFC Basics](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html)

First thing to know is the type of NFC tag you are dealing with (NDEF or other format) from there you should be able to figure out how to scan it from the docs.  If not sure about the tag type you can download one of the many NFC tools in the app store to try and get information from the tag.

Answer (score 0):

NFC works in WebViewGold, if I remember it correctly? We built a NFC WebView app with that approach.
Try this:

```
<a href="readnfc://">Read an NFC Tag</a>
```

and

```
writenfc://?value=data
```

:-)